# Trying to understand Time Complexity - DP Coin Change on Leetcode

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to understand time complexity /how to write more efficient algorithms.

Could someone explain why this first example of a solution for the coin change problem runs faster than the second? The code is cleaner in the first, but what makes it faster? Is it actually faster because there are fewer lines of code?
(forgive me if this is very obvious -- I am only just learning time complexity, my understanding is basically just: nested for loops are exponential, regular loops are linear, basic logic is constant time...)

[Here's a link](https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/) to the problem if you're not familiar

***Better Solution - runs in 18ms***

```
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
    if (amount < 1) return 0;
    int[] dp = new int[amount + 1]; 
    Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    dp[0] = 0;
    for (int coin : coins) {
        for (int i = coin; i <= amount; i++) {
            if (dp[i - coin] != Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
                dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], dp[i - coin] + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return dp[amount] == Integer.MAX_VALUE ? -1 : dp[amount];
}
```

***Worse solution - runs in 26 ms***

```
public int coinChange(int[] coins, int amount) {
       int[] dp = new int[amount+1];
       Arrays.fill(dp, Integer.MAX_VALUE-1);
       dp[0] = 0;

       if(amount == 0){
           return 0;
       }

       for(int j=0; j<coins.length; j++){
           for(int i=1; i<=amount; i++){
               //only continue if coin is less than sum at i
               if(i >= coins[j]){
                   //if there is a smaller sum +1 less than current sum
                   if(dp[i - coins[j]] +1 < dp[i]){
                       dp[i] = 1 + dp[i-coins[j]];
                   }
               }
           }
       }

       if(dp[amount] == Integer.MAX_VALUE-1){
           return -1;
       } else{
           return dp[amount];
       }
    }
```

Comment: Functionally speaking, the first algorithm loops over all coins and can find how many of the current coin is needed to reach `amount` according to the previous count comparing with each of the values in the array, but starting from the current coin index. So this solution is N * (N - C). The second algorithm also find the number of coins needed to reach the amount, but it does that by comparing with each coins, so the solution is N^2. Since we don't care about the constants in Big-O representation, both solutions would be O(N^2), but the first one will perform a little bit better avg.

Comment: Second algo makes unnecessary comparisons. The inner loop should just start from `i=conis[i]` and `if` condition inside can be removed. I thik this is the issue.